# Centering math parameters description

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, variable

I'm working on a document where I need to specify the meaning of different variables in some mathematical equations.
I'm dealing with this code I've found here in the forum (the post is 8 years old actually), anyway I cannot find the way to center the variables.

Here the code sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{conditions*}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
   \tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
  {\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}
An equation just to start
\begin{equation}
P+N=S_{d}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{conditions*}
 P    &  notional permeability factor \\
N     &  number of waves \\
S_{d} &  damage level
\end{conditions*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to get a centered list.

Thank you!

In reply to @Bernard

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
An equation just to start
    \begin{gather}
    P+N=S_{d} \\
    \shortintertext{\indent where:}
    \begin{aligned}
    P & = \text{This is an example where the variable or the parameter could require a longer definition. The width exceed the margins and the linebreak doesn't work.} \\
    N & = \text{number of waves} \\
    S_{d} & = \text{damage level}
    \end{aligned}\notag
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

And that's the result:

[image]

The best thing would be this kind of alignment:

[image]

But more centered, giving it less space to break the line.

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/75s02.png (`\newenvironment{conditions*}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\centering
   \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
`)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much @leandriis. I know it was a bit trivial, but I had no idea where to put the `\centering` command.

Comment: It's not just the centering command that does the trick here, but also the fact that I used a regular tabular instead of tabularx. Be aware though, that automatic linebreaks inside of the second colum are not supported in this modified version  of the code.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you for the warning. I don't think I will need to define variables that require long sentences. However, just for curiosity and if that happens, is there any way to implement automatic linebreaks to not exceed a certain width?

Answer (score 1):

I propose one of these solutions, with an `aligned` environment nested in `gather`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

An equation just to start
\begin{gather}
P+N=S_{d} \\
\shortintertext{where:}
\begin{aligned}
 P & = \text{notional permeability factor} \\
N & = \text{number of waves} \\
S_{d} & = \text{damage level}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
P+N=S_{d} \\
\begin{aligned}
 & \text{where:}\qquad & P & = \text{notional permeability factor} \\
 & & N & = \text{number of waves} \\
 & & S_{d} & = \text{damage level}
\end{aligned}\notag
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bernard. I've tried your code, Is there a way to indent the first "where" so that it is aligned with "An" from the above sentence?

Comment: Oh! yes: use `\shortintertext{\indent where:}`.

Comment: Great @Bernard! I really appreciate your support. Just one last thing I've discussed also with @leandriis: could your code be capable of automatic linebreaks when the second column exceed a certain width? The linebreak capability should align the text keeping it after "=" when the new line starts.

Comment: @Catarella: Possibly (not tested in real situation) if you add `\allowdisplaybreaks` before entering the `gather` environment.

Comment: I've taken your advice @Bernard, but the `\allowdisplaybreaks` command seems to not work properly. Anyway I suppose I won't need to define a really long variable or parameter, but it would be a nice feature just in case.

Comment: @Catarella: could you post a short example with this problem?

Comment: I've updated my first post, so you can find there the example @Bernard.